# SQL Server Managment Studio 2016 fails to open; multiple errors

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Installing this was nothing short of a headache. I had countless issues. In order to install this (16.5.1), I had to uninstall C++ redistributable 14.0.24210, and install version 14.0.23026 in order to get the SSMS install complete.

After installation though, I cannot get the software to work. Upon opening the application, I get the following warnings/errors (in order):

ERROR 1:

```
The 'Visual Studio Debugger' package did not load correctly.
```

ERROR 2:

```
The 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' 
package did not load correctly.
```

The UI then opens, but I am immediately confronted with the following error:

```
===================================

Failed to open connection dialog.

===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.ConnectToOe()
```

The splash screen then pops up with:

```
License: Prerelease software
The license has expired
```

I hit the close button on the splash screen, which closes the entire application.

I have searched for all of these errors, but I was unable to turn up anything related to SSMS 2016. I found only one other person who had this issue who posted on a microsoft connect page, and it was never addressed.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this. The first two messages also said to look at activitylog.xml. Here is my activity log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:42.861</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SSMS version: 2015.130.16100.1</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:42.861</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 version: 14.0.23107.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:52.944</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>Application launch on system with DPI X/Y: 96/96</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>4</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:52.958</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:52.958</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Async Query Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>6</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.102</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Package Framework</source>
    <description>Initialized ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>7</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.108</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Async Query Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>8</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.128</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>9</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.129</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>10</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.129</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Package Framework</source>
    <description>Initialized AsyncServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>11</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.131</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>12</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.152</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>13</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.152</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Image Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>14</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.160</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Image Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.162</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.162</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.175</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.176</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>19</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.176</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Settings Package]</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>20</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.177</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Settings Package]</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>21</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.194</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>22</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.195</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.197</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE*\VsLogUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.203</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>25</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.214</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{3F3D9528-BAC4-420E-8147-29896300C5C0}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.214</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{AA8EB8CD-7A51-11D0-92C3-00A0C9138C45}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>27</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.217</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{512BE089-83EC-4CC6-8483-CF16565AE209}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>28</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.237</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE*\VsLogUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.252</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{68939055-38E0-4D17-92CB-8909710D8178}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: '1'.</errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\*\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.252</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{7B5D447B-0B12-41EA-A84E-C822034422D4}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: '1'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.252</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{D549BC66-C17B-4409-8729-583E60DC0BC1}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: '1'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.266</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: '1'.</errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\*\VSDebugUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>33</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.287</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{D277DC8A-AA1E-4303-8C03-1C58DB18E98B}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>The satellite assembly named "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.resources.dll, Version=14.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5a3a" for fallback culture "en" either could not be found or could not be loaded. This is generally a setup problem. Please consider reinstalling or repairing the application.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>34</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.313</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{87569308-4813-40A0-9CD0-D7A30838CA3F}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: '1000'.</errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Xml\*\Microsoft.XmlEditorUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>35</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.691</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>36</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.691</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.696</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.718</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>39</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.718</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MRU Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>40</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.719</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MRU Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>41</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.821</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>42</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.821</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>43</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>44</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>45</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>46</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{18BEB7F2-CA98-11D1-B6E7-00A0C90F2744}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>47</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>48</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>49</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>50</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.823</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [VSTelemetryPackage]</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>51</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.835</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VSTelemetryPackage]</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>52</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.847</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{EFAEF2D3-8BDB-4D78-B3EB-B55E44203E80}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>53</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.847</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Rules-based UI contexts implementation]</description>
    <guid>{EFAEF2D3-8BDB-4D78-B3EB-B55E44203E80}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>54</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.853</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;AutoLoad Settings Sync&apos; for UI context 1fc0dd70-d72c-4234-8a14-ee6390a214ee.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>55</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.853</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;User Feed Enabled (Delayed)&apos; for UI context 356357f8-56f0-44d1-8e20-a3ad27b9c721.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>56</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.854</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;ActiveProjectSupportsBlend&apos; for UI context 3a014e53-f5ba-4db3-9cd6-9469b8889d1b.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>57</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.854</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;PlatformPaneUIContext&apos; for UI context 5d8b34e5-dff2-44dc-ab45-89c7c6014092.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>58</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.854</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;unnamed&apos; for UI context 64a954ee-b175-40cb-bbc6-ef3673d9ed4c.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>59</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.855</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;BlendSolutionExists&apos; for UI context 7d30c25d-a30b-451a-a4d5-9229204e6aa5.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>60</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.855</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;TriggersPaneUIContext&apos; for UI context 935ad473-5801-4fe3-983a-753b1212c9b3.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>61</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.855</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UI context rules</source>
    <description>Created rule &apos;VSToolWindowUIContext&apos; for UI context fd7ce107-0b2a-409f-8e1c-90bf51caf448.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>62</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.855</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Rules-based UI contexts implementation]</description>
    <guid>{EFAEF2D3-8BDB-4D78-B3EB-B55E44203E80}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>63</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>64</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package]</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>65</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package]</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>66</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>67</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Help Package]</description>
    <guid>{4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>68</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.856</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}</guid>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\*\msenvui.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>69</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.857</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Help Package]</description>
    <guid>{4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>70</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.857</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>71</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.857</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>72</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.919</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>73</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.920</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Debugger]</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>74</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.921</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\*\VSDebugUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>75</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.921</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Debugger]</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>76</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:49:53.921</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Debugger]</description>
    <guid>{C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>77</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:50:56.195</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo>Service provider must implement IVsDebugger interface</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>78</record>
    <time>2016/12/19 19:50:56.196</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo>Service provider must implement IVsDebugger interface</errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Has anyone else had this much trouble with this application? Any ideas what I can try to resolve this?

Comment: You wrote "...In order to install this (16.5.1),...". Do you mean "In order to install SQL Server Management Studio (16.5.1)...."?

Comment: Would you be willing to install the standalone 17.7 version?  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be running the release candidate or BETA version of the management tools. Try downloading the newest version from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

or check the build number of your installer against:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177312

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of .Net framework installed on the machine. If it doesn't meet SSMS 16.5.1 system requirements, install the version required.